# I am looking for a built-in (simple) command to show network usage and bandwidth

Tags: linux, command-line, network-interface

I am working on Linux and looking for a built-in command which can show current network usage and network bandwidth. The built-in means the commands installed by default with the OS. The commands I can think of are `ifconfig`, `ip`, `netstat`. But I couldn't figure out how to use them to calculate current system bandwidth. Below is an output from `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12224259 (11.6 MiB)  TX bytes:4552513 (4.3 MiB)
```

It tells me that the total transferred data is `11.6MB`. I can run the command multiple times with an interval between each. Then I can calculate the current network usage on the network interface `eth0`. But how can I tell the bandwidth of the `eth0` interface?

I did some searching and most of the posts suggest to install additional commands through `apt-get` or `yum` such as `nload`, `iftop`. Since I am building a tool to analyze the network usage on the system, I don't want to add any additional installation requirements to my tools.

Comment: What does "built-in" mean?  Built in to what?  What distro are you using?  How did you get your VM/host?  If I build a package into a VM image, then it's "built in"—so what's wrong with installing a package using the standard package manager for your distribution?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have revised my post. The build-in means the commands shipped with os. Just like the command `ifconfig`, etc.

Comment: See previous comment.  What OS are you using?  How did you install the OS?

Comment: Oh...possibly you are looking for the commands `netstat`, `ip` and `ss`.  They will take some thorough digging through the man pages to master but you shouldn't have to install them before use.  Also `lsof` has uses in analysis of network traffic, and is installed on a default RHEL 6 installation (though not RHEL 7 which omits many previously default packages).  I'm not writing this as an answer because your question is still unclear, and this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Well, since this tagged linux there are files in `/proc` directory which can show number of packets transmitted, if that's what you mean by network usage.  But you'd have to write a script to parse it, so it's not "built-in" as in the sense of built-in command to shell.

Comment: You have already 4 reopen votes, after 5 your question will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the output of `ifconfig` that yields the total data sent on the interface. Using a bash script you could build your own monitoring utility.

If you can install new software, I'd recommend [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs).

Comment: `ifconfig` gives me the total data sent but how I can calculate the bandwidth?

Comment: You could grep the total data send and compare it to the values it was a second ago - then you have the data sent by second.